# Make Author Field in Comments Required

Tags: 7, entities, comments

How I could make from my template.php author/user field in comments required for those who are anonymous users

I tried with this but it didn't work for me

> function MYTHEME_theme() { $form['author']['_author']['#required'] =
>   TRUE; }

I've been searching around but can't find a proper answer :/

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a little module and implement [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) to alter the form.

Answer (score 0):

Make comment name field  mandatory

```
function [Your_modulename]_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

   if ($form_id == 'comment_node_blog_form') {   //if your content type is blog

      $form['author']['name']['#required'] = TRUE;

    }  
}
```